# Swift class containing property of its own type

Tags: swift

I created an iOS app to arbitrate jujitsu/judo fights. My app has a `Fighter` class. In this `Fighter` class I have an `opponent` property that is of type `Fighter` as well. So I have something like this:

```
class Fighter {
    ...
    var opponent: Fighter?
    ...
}

var fighter1 = Fighter()
var fighter2 = Fighter()
fighter1.opponent = fighter2
fighter2.opponent = fighter1
```

I declared it as optional but I'm stuck because I don't want it to be optional, a Fighter **must** have an opponent. It works fine this way but I don't like it and I end up with a lot of unnecessary `if let` or `!`. Plus it's ugly.

How can I do that in a better and safer way?

Comment: Create a Struct/Class Fight and the same with the Fighter. In the Fight object, you can add 2 properties of the type Fighter.

Comment: Unless your fighter is born with his opponent, and is bound to him for his entire life, it's a good idea to move he opponent out into some other class, as suggested  by Fede and David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a Fighter contain another Fighter, create a Match object, that contains two Fighter objects. A type should rarely contain itself.

For example:

```
struct Match{
    let fighterOne: Fighter
    let fighterTwo: Fighter
}
```

Comment: I agree. Fighter should rather contain stuff related to fighter - opponents can change, right?. I think that Fight is more what you are looking for this. A Fight struct with two Fighter structs (I think you don't need a class here - it's simple model). You can also store other stuff there like time, points whatever.

Comment: I do have a Fight object but I just use it to keep record of the different states of the fight. I definitely should have my fighters in it.

I need this opponent var to do things like : (fighter1 gets a penalty that means his opponents get 1 points) 
fighter1.penalty += 1
fighter1.opponent.points += 1

The opponents never change, it's always A versus B. When a new fight begins, all models properties are simply reset.

But I hear that I shouldn't have a Fighter var in my Fighter class.

Comment: You should use the Fight object to delegate events that happen in the fight. For example the Fight class contains a method called Penalty, that issues and takes away points from fighters within the Fight object.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare `opponont` as implicitly unwrapped optional, but I'd rather suggest creating a `Match` class or something similar, where you store the two opponents rather than creating a circular dependency between your `Fighter`s. That would also cause a strong dependency cycle unless you declared the property as `weak/unowned`.

Comment: Like I said in the previous answer, I do have a Fight object. I also declared my opponent var as weak to prevent memory issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
struct Fight {
let fighter1: Fighter
let fighter2: Fighter
var date: Date

}

struct Fighter {
let name: String
let weight: Float
let category: AnyOtherCustomObjectThatYouWant
}
```

Using Structs instead of Class you will have the constructors for free